# preg_match_all explanation

Tags: php, regex

I'm guessing about the exact working of this function in PHP: `preg_match_all`

```
$var = "Example";
$n = preg_match_all('/[AEIOU]/i', strtoupper($var), $matches);

echo "$n<p>"; // Output: 3
echo $matches[0][1]; // Output: A
```

This is almost perfectly clear to me: Find all the matches of vowels in variable `$var` and put their number in `$n`, while the matches found go in the variable `$matches`. But why `$matches` is a bidimensional array if the first index must be 0? Shouldn't it be something like `$matches[1]`? (but it doesn't work)

How can I take advantage of next indexes?

Comment: "Array of all matches in multi-dimensional array ordered according to flags." - from the docs. Read about the flags. http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Does 'because it was designed that way' count for an answer? ) `$matches[1..n]` is very useful when you have to employ capturing groups.

Comment: Note that the i modifier is useless here

Comment: Both the `i` modifier and `strtoupper()` together is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The first index must be 0" because that's the index of the "whole matches". Index 1 would by the first subpattern, if you had any. Index 2 the second subpattern, and so on.

This behaviour can be adjusted with the `PREG_*_ORDER` constants, see the [docs](http://php.net/preg-match-all).

Comment: I didn't know this thing of patterns, but after exploring documentation you linked I seem to understand more about. Since I don't use subpatterns I am sure I can resolve with `$matches = $matches[0];` (Without losing data)